# Fabric.js: Initial position object outside canvas no longer working

Tags: fabricjs

Recently I have started to use a newer version of Fabric.js (from 1.7.22 to 2.3.5). I had to make a few modifications to existing code that seem logical to me. However, I notice that you cannot initially place an object outside the canvas anymore, to reposition it later onto the canvas. Like in the code below. It won't show. My question is: has this changed for some reason, or is this an issue (bug)? And do I have other options than postpone adding the object to the canvas, or using the `visible` attribute?

```js
$( document ).ready(() => {
  const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 301,     
        top: 10,
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top', 
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        fill: '#336699'
    });
    
  canvas.add(rect);      
  rect.set({"left": 10});
  rect.set({"top": 10});
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.5/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `setCoords()` after repositioning.

```js
$( document ).ready(() => {
  const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 301,     
        top: 10,
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top', 
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        fill: '#336699'
    });
    
  canvas.add(rect);      
  rect.set({"left": 10});
  rect.set({"top": 10});
  rect.setCoords();
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.5/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed. However, this raises the question: do I always need `setCoords()` after repositioning? Because I noticed before that objects initially placed on (inside) the canvas did not need it. In other words, what is the use of using `setCoords()` when you need to do it every time?

Comment: @esims [When-to-call-setCoords](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/wiki/When-to-call-setCoords)

Comment: @Durga: meanwhile I also found that page. But the question remains why fabric.js doesn't handle this method itself everytime.

Comment: @esims, calling setCoords for objects in group is not necessary all the time, because group is handeling. and on moving of objects it sets the position. so it is need to call when its necessary.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks.